# Third party cookie to check if the browser block it by default

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to check which browser blocks by default third party cookie.

I though to create a local file .html with a third party cookie and open it to every browser to check it will open. Is this a good option?

I plan to use this example but is it a third party cookie?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create a 1st party cookie - i.e. the domain of this cookie will match the domain of the page loaded.

In order to create a third party cookie you must request a resource from a different domain than the page that requests that resource.  This resource could set a cookie using either javascript or HTTP header command (which is initiated by server side code like PHP).

If you are just doing your own survey to gain information about which browsers accept 3rd party cookies by default then it may be worthwhile looking at the specification for each browser to see what the official line is before going to the effort of testing.